# Android SQLite additional WHERE condition after MATCH

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, android-room

In Android SQLite i got tabel like this

```
domainObjectId: String // like '9876543210'
name: String
description: String
```

I want to use FTS on this to search without worrying about diacritical marks, how ever i want to let user select also by typing part of object ID(ex. last 4 char)

I got select like

```
`SELECT * FROM tabel LEFT JOIN tabel_fts on tabel_fts.domainObjectId = tabel.domainObjectId WHERE tabel_fts MATCH '3210*' OR tabel.domainObjectId LIKE '%3210%'
```

But in return i get error

```
unable to use function MATCH in the requested context (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR);
```

Is this possible to add additional condition to select with `MATCH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove "MATCH" into separate "SELECT":

```
`SELECT * FROM tabel LEFT JOIN (select * from tabel_fts WHERE tabel_fts.domainObjectId MATCH '3210*') as tabel_fts WHERE tabel.domainObjectId LIKE '%3210%' OR table_fts.ID IS   NOT NULL
```

By the way:

1. In your "WHERE tabel_fts" it seemed you've missed a column name
2. There is no "ON" condition in tables JOINm just "WHERE". That's OK? May be it would be better to use UNION?

Comment: `WHERE tabel_fts.domainObjectId MATCH '3210*'` will match only on objectID, without name and description `WHERE tabel_fts MATCH '3210*` will try to mach over entire fts tabel. Your SELECT will work in this case but it wont work if i try to match name, inner select will return values but outter SELECT due LIKE statement will return no values.

Comment: ok, I've got your idea as to WHERE. As for problem with outer|inner select - why then did you choose Left Join? UNION (or Cross JOIN) is not the option?

Comment: looks like it work, `SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE domainObjectId IN ( SELECT domainObjectId FROM tabel WHERE domainObjectId LIKE "%phase%" UNION SELECT number FROM tabel_fts WHERE tabel_fts MATCH "phase*" )`

Comment: it can be done event without UNION ;) `SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE domainObjectId IN (SELECT domainObjectId FROM tabel_fts WHERE tabel_fts MATCH 'phase*' ) OR domainObjectId LIKE '%phase%'`

Comment: Yep. There are lot of options. The only condition is that MATCH should not be used outside its own SELECT.